# I'm trying to pass a string from an input text field on a vf page to the controller and display the results of an updated soql query

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

Hi I'm working on making a super simple vf page that has an input text field so that a user can input a tracking number and the results of the soql query will be displayed beneath it. Initially, my team and I were using two vf pages and that was working in my teammate's org but when I went to deploy it to our production org is wasn't functional. He was using a text field to search but the actual field we needed to reference was an auto number field. Here's the vf page looks like now

```
<apex:page Controller="PackageTrackerController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                Please Enter tracking number.
                <apex:inputText value="{!Tnumber}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Track" action="{!TrackingInfo}" rerender="TrackingTable"/><p />
                <!--  <apex:outputLabel id="Tracker">{!Tnumber}</apex:outputLabel> -->
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Tracking}" var="tnum" id="TrackingTable">
                    <apex:column value="{!tnum.Tracking_Number__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!tnum.Name}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!tnum.Delivery_Status__c}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

and here's the controller

```
public class PackageTrackerController {
    public list<Mail__c> Tracking{get;set;}   
    public string Tnumber{get;set;}
    
    public PackageTrackerController(){
    
           Tracking = [SELECT Name, Tracking_Number__c, Delivery_status__c FROM Mail__c where Tracking_Number__c= :Tnumber];
    
            system.debug(Tracking);

        }
    
        public pagereference TrackingInfo()
        {
            Tracking = [SELECT Name, Tracking_Number__c, Delivery_status__c FROM Mail__c where Tracking_Number__c= :Tnumber];
            system.debug('Value of Tracking' + Tracking);
            return null;
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had copied some spaces into my input text field I hadn't noticed

Comment: That may be something you want to protect against in your Apex